# Declaring two variable in for loop for reversing the string? In c++

Tags: c++, string, loops, for-loop, reverse

```
  for(int i=0,int y=19;i<=19,y>=0;i++,y--)
  {
      char k[y]=char x[i];
  }
```

I have declared `char[20]` for both `k` and `x` ,initialized `x` and now I'm trying to reverse the string. 
It is showing `error expected ;` before `int` and `y was not declared in scope`.

Answer (score 1):

You can reverse the string by declaring it as an array, and then declaring an integer equal to the last letter's spot( first letter = 0).

```
int letter [6] = {l, e, t, t, e, r};
int x = 5;

for ( int x = 5; x>= 0; x--) {
cout<<letter[x];
}
```

Comment: So much wrong there...

Comment: can you explain the error please

Comment: Your answer is just wrong. `for (int i=0,j=100; i <  100;  i++, j--)` is perfectly correct. Semicolons separate the three sections of the `for` construct, and commas separate multiple actions within each. Read the answer to the linked question

Comment: Also the line `Int y = 19;` is incorrect (`Int` vs. `int`), and irrelevant, as you then try to define `y` in the loop.

Comment: And finally, the line you copied from the question `char k[y]=char x[i]` is simply meaningless.

Comment: i have made it work ,by removing int from for loop and declaring int before loop,,thanks everyone for nothing turns out stackovereflow is much less helpful than i anticipated ,,,thanks roddy for pointing in right direction

Answer (score 1):

this code reverses only one string

```
for(int i=0;i<length/2;i++)
{
    char temp= k[i];
´   k[i] = k[length-1-i];
    k[length-1-i] = temp;
}
```

Comment: No, it doesn't. Try reversing the string "ab" (length=2) and see what happens.

Comment: @Roddy if we insert "ab" the for loop will be executed once. temp gets the value "a", k[i] gets the value "b", k[length-1-i] so k[2-1-0] so k[1] gets the value "a" so at the end there is "ba"